# Mapped-list patterns which act like enumerate

Tags: python

So I am creating a function which behaves in a similar way to the built-in enumerate function but returns a list of tuples (index, value).

This is my function:

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    """return a list of tuples (i, item) where item is the ith item, 
    with 0 origin, of the list items"""
    result = []
    for i in items:
        tuples = ((items.index(i)), i)
        result.append(tuples)
    return result
```

So when testing with the following:

```
ans = my_enumerate([10, 20, 30])
print(ans)
```

It will return:

```
[(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30)]
```

So it does work, but when testing with:

```
ans = my_enumerate(['x', 'x', 'x'])
print(ans)
```

It returns:

```
[(0, 'x'), (0, 'x'), (0, 'x')]
```

Where it should be:

```
[(0, 'x'), (1, 'x'), (2, 'x')]
```

How can I get it so it returns this instead?

Comment: Sorry, how is your intended output different from `enumerate` itself?

Comment: Its for school lab, where were not suppose to use the enumerate function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `items.index(i)`. The `index` function returns the first index if there are multiple of the same object. Since you have 3 `'x'`, it will always return the index of the first `'x'`.

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    """
    return a list of tuples (i, item) where item is the ith item, with 0 origin, of the list items
    """

    result = []
    for index in range(len(items)):
        tuples = (index, items[index])
        result.append(tuples)

    return result
```

Comment: Please don't use answers as comments. If you have questions, leave them in the comments on the question.

Comment: No, it is an answer.

Comment: That would probably work but the problem. Its part of an exercise for school where the function is not suppose to call the in-built enumerate function.